# `Float` type not recognizing float numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, prisma

I'm trying to mutate (save) longitude and latitude into Postgres through GraphQL.  The numbers are something like -79.39048179999998.
My client side schema:

```
input CreatePostInput {
    longitude: Float!
    latitude: Float!
}
```

My Prisma schema:

```
type Post {
    longitude: Float!
    latitude: Float!
```

Mutation gql:

```
mutation CreatePost($longitude: Float!, $latitude: Float!) {
    createPost(data: {
        longitude: $longitude, latitude: $latitude
        }
    ){
      id
    }
  }
```

console.logging both longitude and latitude before being input to graphql shows that they're both properly defined, but when I look at Postgres, they only show up as "0.000000000000000000000000000000".  I even tried `const longitude = Number(longitude)` just to make sure they're numbers, but still get the same result. There are other variables within the same mutation, which I've redacted for simplicity in this case, that get saved properly in Postgres.  This tells me that the mutation itself is working properly.

Resolver:

```
createPost(parent, args, { prisma, request }, info) {
        const userId = getUserId(request)
        return prisma.mutation.createPost({
            data: {
                longitude: args.data.longitude,
                latitude: args.data.latitude,
            }   
        }, info)
    },
```

Comment: I can't replicate this. Although it does round off 7 places past the decimal to "-79.390481800000000000000000000000". If you're looking in pgAdmin, double click the value as it shows the end of the number which is all 0s.

Comment: Would you also provide your resolver? Also how are you providing your query variables? Are you using the playground?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply.  @Andrew1325 I am using pgAdmin, but doubclicking the value shows 0.  I've also tried fetching the data back which shows 0.

Comment: @Dom I included the resolver in the post now.  I am not using the playground, but creating the data from the front end.